# DD4T with Session Preview with Image deployed to file system possible?

Tags: dd4t, session-preview

I'm trying to configure a website that has Experience Manager with Session Preview enabled on a 2011 SP1 DD4T application.  I have it working when everything is published to the Database.  My problem is that I want to configure the deployer, content delivery to look and publish binaries to the filesystem.  When I configure that, the Update Preview seems to break (basically does not show the updated items and keeps saying to update preview) Is it possible to have a hybrid application with session preview?  Publish binaries to the file system and the rest to the broker database?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you're on .net or on java.

**Microsoft.NET**

You can do this by configuring the folder which holds your (published) binaries separately from the main application.

Let's say your binaries are in the subfolder 'binaries'. The Web.config in the root of your site should NOT have the PreviewContentModule enabled. Just create a new Web.config inside the binaries folder, with the following contents:

```
 ...
 <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" />
    </httpModules> 
  </system.web>
  ...
```

**Java**

On java, there is a filter instead of an HttpModule. Here, it's slightly easier to do what you want, since filters (unlike HttpModules) CAN be mapped to urls. That way, you could serve binaries through the filter and pages without the filter.

Comment: The content delivery app is .net.  Couldn't I configure the module to intercept specific file types?  Like *.jpg, *.png etc?

Comment: I've thought about it some more, and I think it is possible after all. See my edited answer.